# SwiftUI and Combine Observable object having @Published is constantly publishing

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have such view model for search bar that has search done on term typed into bar. Then it make request and assigns to results.

```
class SearchViewModel<T>: ObservableObject {

    @Published var searchTerm = ""
    @Published var results: [T] = []

    private var disposables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        $searchTerm
            .debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
            .flatMap { term in
                self.search(by: term)
            }
            .print("searching")
            .assign(to: \.results, on: self)
            .store(in: &disposables)
    }

    open func search(by term: String) -> AnyPublisher<[T], Never> {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

View is checking based on this $viewModel.results whether to display Results View in over fullscreen mode or not.

But in spite of search being generally hidden (if user not tap onto button) there is constantly something happaning in this Publisher stream

```
2019-12-06 23:45:09.810053+0100 CRM[1589:440623] [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.
Dim drag (19.666656494140625, -1.6666717529296875)
searching: receive subscription: (FlatMap)
searching: request unlimited
Dim drag (42.33332824707031, -7.6666717529296875)
End dim drag: (56.33332824707031, -13.333328247070312)
searching: receive subscription: (FlatMap)
searching: request unlimited
searching: receive subscription: (FlatMap)
searching: request unlimited
searching: receive subscription: (FlatMap)
searching: request unlimited
Search button tapped!
searching: receive value: ([])
searching: receive value: ([])
searching: receive value: ([])
searching: receive value: ([])
```

It is odd as this should be triggered only on input (term) typed into the field.

I think here is something wrong.

UPDATE!

important this multiple searchning stream logs appear in console where there is dragged in Hamburger menu if it is shown using bar button then there is only one refresh. It's a little bit wierd that showing view (or rather moving it with offset causes @Published var term to get new input, and also I see that my List content is then refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious test environment to use that, but in that I've reconstructed using filter as below helped

```
.debounce(for: .seconds(1), scheduler: DispatchQueue.global())
.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
```

anyway in such use-cases avoiding re-search for same term is also useful.